# execute full js function when button is pressed and page changes

Tags: javascript

I have an html page which contains a button that is an "add to cart" button. When this button is clicked the page reroutes to the cart.

```
<button type="submit" name="add" class="action_button add_to_cart" onclick="return postScreenShot()" data-label="Add to Cart"><span class="text">Add to Cart</span></button>
```

What I need to happen is that when a user clicks on this button the method `postScreenShot` is executed.

`postscreenShot` method contains:

```
function postScreenShot() {
    'https://example.com/'+previewImageId+'.png');
    var productName = $(".product_name").text();
    var customText = $("#user_input").val();
    var secondCustomText = $("#second_user_input").val();
    var getImage = $("#img_preview_fancybox div").find("img").attr("src");
    var licensePlateImage = getImage.replace('https://example.com/preview/img/','');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            firstLine: customText,
            secondLine: secondCustomText,
            previewId: previewImageId,
            prodName: productName
        },
        url: 'https://example.com/doit',
    }); 
}
```

What I need is for the entire method to run but the problem that appears to be happening is that the page reroutes before completion of the method.

What I did was put it here expecting it to run my method and that it would wait for it to return.

```
onClick="return postScreenShot()"
```

What would be the correct way to do this or is it not possible?

Comment: _"This would then return the postScreenShot() function"_ — actually what this returns is the _result of running_ the postScreenShot function. Then, since you clicked on a button, whatever the default action of that button is will happen, unless postScreenShot returns `false`. You'll need to post some HTML showing what the structure looks like, and probably some more of your javascript, to get an answer that is not just guesswork. [ask]

Comment: @StephenP Ok I will later today.

Comment: Like stephen already explained a bit. A function is not loaded by a click, it was loaded before else it doesn't exist and gives an `undefined` error. What a click does in your case is call a defined function. *(some people also say execute a function)* A function is a routine to do something and perhaps also return a value. Return means pass something back to the part of code that placed the call. It can be used to cancel the click event, like stephen said if the routine has a reason to return `false`. For example if some input was incorrect or something couldn't be done during the routine.

Comment: @StephenP updated.

Comment: Since the button is `type="submit"` it is going to (attempt to) submit the data and refresh the page (or go to a new page) In Avin Kavish' answer the **"prevent default action"** is what stops the button from doing that automatically, and instead do only what you write in your own code.

Comment: Ya makes sense, it's just not working lol  @StephenP , I'm wondering if the button is being called by jquery event handler.  I'm not the original coder of the whole thing so it's a little difficult to dig through everything.

Comment: Never mind dumb me, I wasn't binding to the form.  It worked @StephenP

Comment: Great FabricioG!  I suggest the next thing you learn is how to use [`element.addEventListener(event, function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline "onclick" type handlers. Inline handlers are the "bad old days"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate once the POST is complete by using the `done` callback.

```html
<button ... onclick="postScreenShot(event)">
```

```js
function postScreenShot(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent default action

  'https://example.com/'+previewImageId+'.png');
  var productName = $(".product_name").text();
  var customText = $("#user_input").val();
  var secondCustomText = $("#second_user_input").val();
  var getImage = $("#img_preview_fancybox div").find("img").attr("src");
  var licensePlateImage = getImage.replace('https://example.com/preview/img/','');


  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     data: {firstLine: customText,
            secondLine: secondCustomText,
            previewId: previewImageId,
             prodName: productName
           },
     url: 'https://example.com/doit',
   }).done(function () { $("#form-selector").submit();  });  // <-- submit the form on done
};
```